# код не работает, я не могу понять почему

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 650))

class guy:

    x = random.randrange(30, 501, 235)
    y = -70

    def osn(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(sc, (255, 255, 255), (guy.x, guy.y , 70, 70))
        guy.y - 10
        if guy.y <= -650:
            y = 70

guy1 = guy()
guy2 = guy()

while 1:

    guy1.osn()
    guy2.osn()

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.delay(60)
```

Тут должны появляться квадраты, которые должны двигаться вниз и при достижении определённых координат возвращаться на верх. Квадраты не появляются вообще.

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос (включая название) так, чтобы было понятно, что вы хотели сделать, что не получается и т. д. Иначе вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: извините больше так не буду делать

Comment: Я вообще не вижу причин, почему этот код должен работать ожидаемым образом. У вас совершенно несуразный класс (где у вас инициализация объекта? почему в методах класса используются атрибуты класса, а не экземпляра/объекта?), который плодит прямоугольники с одними и теми же координатами для всех объектов.

Comment: Я начал заниматься программированием недавно и плохо в этом смыслю но благодаря вам я понял свои ошибки и буду учитывать их в дальнейшем

Comment: Не корректируйте код вопроса, внося правки из ответов. В будущем никто не поймет, о чем собственно был сам вопрос, если указан совершенно рабочий код. Отправлю заявку на отмену правок

Comment: извините сделал не подумав о том что это может кому-нибудь пригодиться

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должен примерно выглядеть ваш код:

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 650))

class Guy():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(30, 501, 235)
        self.y = -70

    def osn(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(sc, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y , 70, 70))
        self.y += 10
        if self.y <= -650:
            self.y = 70

guy1 = Guy()
guy2 = Guy()

while True:
    sc.fill((0,0,0))

    guy1.osn()
    guy2.osn()

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.delay(60)
```

Обратите внимание на класс `Guy` и его метод `__init__()`, являющийся конструктором экземпляра данного класса. Именно в нем определяются стартовые атрибуты экземпляра. Ссылаться на сам экземпляр необходимо через аргумент `self`.

Comment: спасибо за помощь и предоставленный вами код

Answer (score 0):

Ну наверное вот тут:

```
guy.y - 10
```

Должно было быть так:

```
guy.y -= 10
```

И вообще не очень понятно у вас то `y`, то `guy.y` используется. Там наверное вообще `self.y` должен быть в функции `osn`, если у вас не на все экземпляры одна переменная, а на каждый экземпляр своя.

Comment: спасибо что указали на мои ошибки я их исправлю